Unable to share my project to Github with Android Studio
I have tried everything that I was doing in the previous Android Studio version, but somehow I am not able to share my project on GitHub with Android Studio. Kindly suggest me ways to solve this issue, for now I am stuck and not able to work properly.
I tried through steps(VCS > GitHub > Share Your project on github), but that was not working for me also I tried with steps (settings > Version Control > GitHub) sometimes it shows (bad credentials) but in my case it is "OK" everything is fine. If it is "Bad Credentials" then you have to re-login through your password. Now I am stuck in a situation where I am unable to share my work on Github. I should have the respective laptop to work on the project. Kindly do help me!
Here is the error
